# Haskell's `otherwise` is a synonym for `_`?

Tags: haskell

I ran across a piece of code recently that used Haskell's `otherwise` to pattern match on a list. This struck me as odd, since:

```
ghci> :t otherwise
otherwise :: Bool
```

So, I tried the following:

```
ghci> case [] of otherwise -> "!?"
"!?"
```

I also tried it with various other patterns of different types and with `-XNoImplicitPrelude` turned on (to remove `otherwise` from scope), and it still works. Is this supposed to happen? Where is this documented?

Comment: In the prelude, it defines `otherwise = True`. Using it in a pattern match just shadows that definition, introducing a new, more local variable which also happens to be called `otherwise`. A similar example is `case "shadowing can be confusing" of (==) -> "Y'know, " ++ (==)`, which returns `"Y'know, shadowing can be confusing"`.

Comment: Just since nobody has said it yet, `otherwise` is supposed to be used as a guard expression, not a pattern. `case ... of pat | ... -> ... | otherwise -> ...` Now its definition as `True` is important.

Comment: @AndrewC, great example!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not equivalent to `_`, it's equivalent to any other identifier. That is if an identifier is used as a pattern in Haskell, the pattern always matches and the matched value is bound to that identifier (unlike `_` where it also always matches, but the matched value is discarded).

Just to be clear: the identifier `otherwise` is not special here. The code could just as well have been `x -> "!?"`. Also, since the binding is never actually used, it would make more sense to use `_` to avoid an "unused identifier" warning and to make it obvious to the reader that the value does not matter.

Comment: `case [] of otherwise -> (otherwise, "!?")` is `([], "!?")` is an example showing how the binding works in this case.

Comment: Thanks!

So it's just another variable. I should have known... * gently bangs head on wall repeatedly *.

Comment: Just remember `otherwise = True`.  Some people even use `True` instead of `otherwise` in their code which sometimes reads oddly but also avoids unintended binding.

Answer (score 11):

> Just since nobody has said it yet, otherwise is supposed to be used as a guard expression, not a pattern. case ... of pat | ... -> ... | otherwise -> ... Now its definition as True is important. –  Reid Barton

An example:

```
fact n acc
  | n == 0 = acc
  | otherwise = fact (n-1) $! (acc * n)
```

Since `otherwise` is `True`, that second guard will always succeed.

Note that using `otherwise` in a pattern (as opposed to a guard) is likely to confuse people. It will also trip a name shadowing warning if GHC is run with the appropriate warnings enabled.